# Using gspread AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'get_addr_int'

Tags: python, gspread

I'm using gspread to modify a Google Sheets, but I keep getting this error when I run it:

AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'get_addr_int'

Here is my code:

```html
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

json_key = ###
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

sheet = gc.open("worksheet")

sh = sheet.sheet1
dates_array = sh.row_values(2)
col = len(dates_array) 
signin_array = sheet.worksheets()[1:]
id_array = sh.col_values(3)[2:]
 if signin.title in dates_array:
  continue 
 col += 1
 sh.update_cell(2, col, signin.title)
 cell = sh.get_addr_int(2, col)
```

I have also tried using "rowcol_to_a1" and "utils.rowcol_to_a1" and got the same error.